# Import sheets from Excel files located in different folder in R

Tags: r, excel, loops, import, readxl

Basically I have two Excel files with the same name "Checklist" in two different folder (one is 2018 and the other one is 2019). Checklist has different sheets, one for each month : "January", "February" etc... Of course, all the sheets have exactly the same variables. 
I would like to put in the same data frame all the sheets from both Excel files. 
For now, I can gather the sheets from one Excel File with :

```
library(readxl)   
library(tibble)
read_excel_allsheets <- function(filename, tibble = TRUE) {
  sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(filename)
  x <- lapply(sheets, function(X) readxl::read_excel(filename, sheet = X))
  if(!tibble) x <- lapply(x, as.data.frame)
  names(x) <- sheets
  x
}

mysheets <-read_excel_allsheets("C:/Users/Thiphaine/Documents/2018/Checklist.xlsx")
library(dplyr)
mysheets<-bind_rows(mysheets, .id = "column_label")
```

I just don't know how to create a loop that will go through the folder 2018 and 2019 to gather all the sheets from both Excel file. The idea will also be that in 2020, I will have another folder "2020" that should be included... Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
allsheets <- list()
for(file in list.files(path = "PATH/TO/DCUMENTS/", 
    recursive = TRUE, pattern = "*.xlsx", full.names = TRUE)) {
  mysheets <- read_excel_allsheets(file)
  mysheets <- bind_rows(mysheets, .id = "column_label") 
  allsheets[[file]] <- mysheets
}
```

where `PATH/TO/DOCUMENTS` is probably something like `"C:/Users/Thiphaine/Documents/` for you.

Comment: Thanks Alko, I have a message error "Error: `path` does not exist: ‘Checklist.xlsx’"

Comment: Did you use the edited code? The first one I wrote assumed that you are reading files under your working directory. If you use `full.names = TRUE` it makes a list of the full paths of all the files.

Comment: Actually it works now but i only get the data from one of the folder

Comment: Check if ` list.files(path = "PATH/TO/DCUMENTS/", recursive = TRUE, pattern = "*.xlsx", full.names = TRUE)` gives you the list of all the files you want to extract. If yes, then there is the code you added to write the files that has the issue. Probably it overwrites the results.

Comment: I edited the answer with a way to make a list of all sheets.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like can also vectorize it using the `tidyverse` approach. Especially because all of your files are the same (column names) and you want to end up with a `data.frame`.

```
require(tidyverse)

df <- list.files(path = "your_path",
                       full.names = TRUE,
                       recursive = TRUE,
                       pattern = "*.xls") %>% 
tbl_df() %>%
mutate(sheetName = map(value, readxl::excel_sheets)) %>%
unnest(sheetName) %>% 
mutate(myFiles = purrr::map2(value, sheetName, function(x,y) {
    readxl::read_excel(x, sheet = paste(y))})) %>% 
unnest(myFiles)
```

Comment: It kind of work except that some dates are converted into numbers.. But basically with this approach, I don't need my code to import each sheets ?! Which line do it ? I'm not sure to understand the code here

Comment: It works but I have some really weird rows :  "<U+0414><U+0430><U+0442><U+0430> / Date" so I'm trying to skip the first 5 rows that are useless in my file with "read_excel(x, sheet = paste(y), skip=4)" on the 7th of the code but I have a warning "Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : Column `<U+0414><U+0430><U+0442><U+0430> / Date` can't be converted from character to POSIXct/POSIXt"

Comment: It seems like your excel date/time format is probably inconsistent or wrong. How many columns do you have in your sheets? if not many, you can define them before reading (instead of letting the `read_excel` function to guess) using the `col_types` argument. These are your options: "skip", "guess", "logical", "numeric", "date", "text" or "list". Thus, your date/time format define as "text" and not "date"

Comment: you can look here for more info about `read_excel` arguments https://readxl.tidyverse.org/reference/read_excel.html

Comment: So, I put the col_types argument and I end up with 50 warnings as this one :  1: In read_fun(path = enc2native(normalizePath(path)), sheet_i = sheet,  ... : Expecting date in A6 / R6C1: got '01.11.2018'   and some NA instead of some date. But what's weird if sometimes for the same sheet, I have some dates and NA...

Comment: That's b/c your dates are not written in a consistent manner and in some cases  `POSIXct/POSIXt` doesn't mange to change it into a date format and thus return it as `NA`. Try loading one file with the function and debug it.