# Read All Excel Files into R by Sheet with file name as column

Tags: r, plyr, readr, readxl

I have a local folder with excel files in the same format. Each excel file has 10 sheets.

I want to be able to do the following:

1) Read all the excel files in R

2) Rbind all the results together but **by sheet**.

3) Result would be 10 new dataframes with all the excel files rbinded together.

4) New column will be added with file name

I have looked up code and the best I could find is this but it doesn't do it by sheet:

```
files = list.files()
library(plyr)
library(readr)
library(readxl)
data2=lapply(files, read_excel)
for (i in 1:length(data2)){data2[[i]]<-cbind(data2[[i]],files[i])}
all_data <- do.call("rbind.fill", data2)
```

Has anyone had any success with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `readxl::excel_sheets` is your friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like you can also vectorize it using the `tidyverse` approach.

```
require(tidyverse)

df <- list.files(path = "your_path",
                       full.names = TRUE,
                       recursive = TRUE,
                       pattern = "*.xls") %>% 
tbl_df() %>%
mutate(sheetName = map(value, readxl::excel_sheets)) %>%
unnest(sheetName) %>% 
mutate(myFiles = purrr::map2(value, sheetName, function(x,y) {
    readxl::read_excel(x, sheet = paste(y))})) %>% 
unnest(myFiles)
```

*Somehow I was unable to flag it, so I'm copying my answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54549579/import-sheets-from-excel-files-located-in-different-folder-in-r/54550644)

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to have them as separate dataframes instead of all in 1? I would like each sheet name to be it's own dataframe since each sheet is in a different format. So the expected result would be 10 different dataframes representing each sheet rbinded with all the files in that folder.

Comment: Figured out a workaround with your code as a base. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I apologize, just seen your comment. You're welcome! :)