# How to write efficient code for importing multiple SAS files

Tags: r

I am struggling with creating efficient code for importing SAS data file.

My code is the follow:

```
library(foreign)
library(haven)
f <- file.path(path = "E:/Cohortdata/Raw cohort/Nationalscreeningcohort/01.jk", 
               c("nhis_heals_jk_2002.sas7bdat","nhis_heals_jk_2003.sas7bdat" ,"nhis_heals_jk_2004.sas7bdat",
                 "nhis_heals_jk_2005.sas7bdat","nhis_heals_jk_2006.sas7bdat","nhis_heals_jk_2007.sas7bdat",
                 "nhis_heals_jk_2008.sas7bdat","nhis_heals_jk_2009.sas7bdat","nhis_heals_jk_2010.sas7bdat",       "nhis_heals_jk_2011.sas7bdat","nhis_heals_jk_2012.sas7bdat","nhis_heals_jk_2013.sas7bdat"))
d <- lapply (f, read_sas)
```

I know rewriting it with for loop would be much more efficient, but don't know how the code should be look like

I would be very thankful if you help me.

Comment: Are you trying to read *every* `sas7bdat` file in the folder? That would make it easier to simplify the code.

Comment: Yes, that exactly what I am trying to do. My sas7bdat files are stored in a folder. What  I don't like in my code is that I am writing name of all sas files, but the desired code is with for loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a variation of a code that I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54859393/read-all-excel-files-into-r-by-sheet-with-file-name-as-column/54860341#54860341) but you can use it for SAS files too.

Please note that instead of using `file.path()` I used `list.files()`. That allowed me to read all the files in the path `"E:/Cohortdata/Raw cohort/Nationalscreeningcohort"`, which is where I assumed your files are. In addition, I used the argument `pattern` to look only for `sas7bdat` files.

`list.files()` returns a vector, here you can use your `*apply` method that you'd like. However, I like changing the `vector` to `tbl_df` and to use the the `tidyverse` approach. Which means reading all the files using `purrr::map()` (part of `tidyverse`) and create a big data `tbl_df` of all of the files.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(foreign)
library(haven)

df <- list.files(path = "E:/Cohortdata/Raw cohort/Nationalscreeningcohort",
                 full.names = TRUE,
                 recursive = TRUE,
                 pattern = "*.sas7bdat") %>% 
  tbl_df() %>%
  mutate(data = map(value, read_sas)) %>%
  unnest(data)
```