# import all SAS files in folder and convert labels to column names in R

Tags: r, sas, r-haven, r-labelled

Following on from post ([How to write efficient code for importing multiple SAS files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55215337/how-to-write-efficient-code-for-importing-multiple-sas-files)) I have used the below to load all SAS files into an R dataframe/tibble, however the label names are lost in unnest() step. How can one perform operations on the df$data list object to convert the SAS labels to column names?
Is there a way to add in an sjlabelled::label_to_colnames() or haven::as_factor() prior to unnesting that acts on the df$data list?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(foreign)
library(haven)

df <- list.files(path = "E:/Cohortdata/Raw cohort/Nationalscreeningcohort",
                 full.names = TRUE,
                 recursive = TRUE,
                 pattern = "*.sas7bdat") %>% 
  tbl_df() %>%
  mutate(data = map(value, read_sas)) %>%
  unnest(data) 
``
```

Comment: could you please convert the `sas7bdat` to `xpt` and then use haven::read_xpt function to read the files, which will retain the column labels

Answer (score 0):

Edit found a solution incase helps anyone else

data.table::rbindlist() rowbinds the list column (df$data) of SAS files

as.data.frame() %>%  label_to_colnames() converts to a dataframe and swaps the SAS labels to column names

```
library(tidyverse)
library(haven)
library(sjlabelled)
library(janitor)

df <- list.files(path = "R:/James/path",
                 full.names = TRUE,
                 recursive = TRUE,
                 pattern = "*.sas7bdat") %>% as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(data = map(value, read_sas)) 

df1<- data.table::rbindlist(df$data, fill=T) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%  label_to_colnames() %>% clean_names()
```

Comment: Without any explanation this answer is incomplete. For example which  of the 7 or more function calls is the one that is converting the labels into the names?